# Array function removes first char from the array

Tags: c, arrays, function, character

I am trying to write a function for a bigger project that consists of working with character arrays. The current function I am working on, is supposed to save only alphabetical characters and remove any special characters (Ex: ! # @ $ ? ) and spaces. My current function works, but for some reason when I run it, the first character of the array is always removed. Why is that and how can I make it to save the first character instead?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char phrase[101];

  printf("Enter a phrase to change:");
  fgets(phrase, 101, stdin);

  printf("original phrase: %s", phrase);

  int i = 0, j = 0;
  while(phrase[i] != '\0')
  {
    if( ('A' <= phrase[i] && phrase[i] >= 'Z') || 
        ('a' <= phrase[i] && phrase[i] >= 'z') )
    {
       phrase[j] = phrase[i];
       i++;
       j++;
    }
    else
      i++;

    phrase[j] = '\0';
  }

  printf("new phrase: %s\n", phrase);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direction of your comparison operators is wrong. Instead of:

```
if( ('A' <= phrase[i] && phrase[i] >= 'Z') || 
    ('a' <= phrase[i] && phrase[i] >= 'z') )
```

You need:

```
if( ('A' <= phrase[i] && phrase[i] <= 'Z') || 
    ('a' <= phrase[i] && phrase[i] <= 'z') )
```

The way you wrote it will skip uppercase letters, which is probably why it skipped the first character of your input.

You should also move the line `phrase[j] = '\0';` to after the loop, because otherwise you may overwrite the next character to be read.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm guessing the first character isn't alphanumeric. You have a line specifically removing it:

```
phrase[j] = '\0';
```

Either you remove the first character (if it's not alphanumeric), or you remove the second (if the first *is* alphanumeric).

You should put the trailing \0 only after you're done scanning your string.

EDIT: As @interjay pointed out, your check is wrong, so your first character is *always* treated as not alphanumeric. That's why you erase it.

Comment: Yeah I found once I switched my checks it was necesary to have that outside of the loop, other wise I wouldn't get the correct output. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess because your first character is the only upper-case one, and your logic is wrong.

```
if( ('A' <= phrase[i] && phrase[i] >= 'Z') ||    
     ('a' <= phrase[i] && phrase[i] >= 'z') )
```

should be

```
if( ('A' <= phrase[i] && phrase[i] <= 'Z') ||    
     ('a' <= phrase[i] && phrase[i] <= 'z') )
```

although the C library does provide isalpha which would also work on EBCDIC character sets where 'A' to 'Z' are not consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `isalpha()` from `ctype.h`?

```
if (isalpha(phrase[i])) {
    phrase[j] = phrase[i];
    /* ... */
}
```

But to speak about your question:

The `while` loop is only visited once, since the predicate of the loop is not met after the first time it is executed, because you set `phrase[j]` to `'\0'` in the first time the loop is run.

Edit: Oh, I have not read the `if` condition carefully.  As @interjay points out, it is *also* wrong.